# TT summer salary withheld despite prior commitment

Tags: united-states, professorship, tenure-track, salary

I'm a tenure-track faculty at an R1 university with a standard 9-mo appointment. At the end of July, I have decided to move to another tenure-track position at another R1 university (for personal reasons). I immediately notified the chair of my department (by email), who was aware of my personal reasons and received the information amicably. The move will happen in one year. Perhaps importantly, I have not yet submitted a formal resignation notice/letter.

Before the summer term began (and before my giving notice), the staff in my department had asked about my expected work commitment for the summer, and where would my funding come from. I proposed to work at 100% effort and to pull my summer salary from my startup (which had been done in the past without any issues). Accordingly, my 1st month summer salary this year was paid as expected. However, my 2nd month summer salary was not paid, and I expect my 3rd month to not be paid either.

I've reached out to the HR person and the department Chair. The Chair said that I can no longer use my startup funds to pay summer salary, since I'll be leaving the University within one year. While I understand their approach, nobody had informed me of this rule. My contract states that I have discretion on how to use my startup -- including using it for summer salary -- but that its use requires approval. Keep in mind that my summer salary had been approved when I first requested it.

So far, I have been working during the summer as previously agreed with the department. Accordingly, I don't think it's fair to have my summer salary withheld ***after*** having running my lab at 100% effort. Am I wrong to expect my summer payment as previously agreed upon?

Comment: Presumably when you started your position, you signed some sort of contract and this likely mentioned startup funds and any limits on those funds. Possibly you will find this policy there.

Comment: You need to work this out locally, perhaps with the help of legal counsel. Opinions here won't change anything.

Comment: It's quite common to have a clause in a contract or faculty handbook that requires faculty to repay sabbatical leave salary if the faculty member leaves shortly after the sabbatical (or never returns.)  It wouldn't be surprising if a similar clause applied to your startup funds.   Beyond that, it's no surprise that your funds were frozen once you announced your intention to leave the university.  Don't be surprised if you're prevented from using the funds to support students or buy equipment.